# Redefinition of a bash alias

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I want to be able to redefine the alias in the function.

I've played around and found that this can be achieved by simply defining a new alias in the function with the same name(see example below).

However I doubt very much that this is a correct way to do. What would be the best practice to achieve the same result?

The example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# alias.sh

shopt -s expand_aliases
# Must set this option, else script will not expand aliases.

alias testal="echo 1"
testal


settestal() {
    echo "in f: call testal"
    testal
    echo "in f: redefine"
    alias testal="echo '2'"
    echo "in f: call testal"
    testal
    echo "in f: end f"
}

settestal

testal
```

As a result one would see:

```
1
in f: call testal
1
in f: redefine
in f: call testal
1
in f: end f
2
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct?

Comment: ...the only thing that's unusual here is using an alias *at all*, rather than a function alone.

Comment: Why don't you think this is the correct way? What would be better?

Comment: (You can redefine functions in functions too, but it's also easier to parameterize functions or otherwise include conditional logic in ways that makes redefinition unnecessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in any way incorrect about this, and the only respect in which I'd call your practices questionable is using aliases in a noninteractive context at all.

While aliases are *currently* (as of the 2013 revision) part of the baseline POSIX sh standard, for most of that standard's lifetime they were in the (optional) User Portability Utilities extensions or nonspecified entirely.

---

For comparison, the equivalent using functions -- which, you'll note, simply provides new definitions with the same names, exactly as you're already doing with aliases:

```
testal() { echo 1; }
testal

settestal() {
    echo "in f: call testal"
    testal
    echo "in f: redefine"
    testal() { echo 2; }
    echo "in f: call testal"
    testal
    echo "in f: end f"
}

settestal
testal
```

Comment: I want to do a trick like this because I have a several working projects and for all of them I want to define similar working tools. But those tools  'definitions' are dependent from the configuration of the current working project. Redefining the aliases was the first thing which came into my mind.

Comment: Why not have a function that looks at what directory it's in and does a different thing for each?

Comment: My motivation would be because I group a rather small number of commands to each alias. If I would use functions instead with if-statements for each possible directory the code size would grow very fast. I think that in my situation now I can switch to functions (and I will, thank you) but if I would have more of the directories/projects this could be problematic. Or maybe I am imagining it wrong?

Comment: @greyxray, you can conditionally run suffixed commands. `testal_foo() { ... }`, `testal_bar() { ... }`, `testal_baz() { ... }`, and have your `testal` look at whether there exists another function with its name plus a suffix that matches the name of the project your current directory is in. I've given someone a recipe for doing this elsewhere on StackOverflow. That one function is a little hairy, but you can reuse it (so long as it inspects its own name to find the thing to prefix), and automate the process of defining several such "switch" functions.

Comment: ...that way, adding another project is a matter only of defining a `testal_newproject()` function, not of changing your `testal()` function.